# Spayed female cat pees on bed

Tags: cats

We have an almost 2-year-old spayed female cat. She was 10 months old when she came to live with us (me and my husband). She was really stressed out the first couple of months and she went into hiding most of the time until she got used to us.

She went into heat as soon as we got her, and she peed all around the house beginning with our bed. The peeing continued a little while after spaying.  According to the vet, it must have been due to the hormones left in her system and it should have eventually ceased. In the meanwhile, we stopped letting her inside the bedroom. After a couple of months, the peeing outside the litter box stopped, so we decided to let her into the bedroom. But she peed on the bed again. We tried this a couple of times, and saw that every time we let her inside the bedroom, she pees on the bed. And she does it when we are in the bed. The smell is almost as bad as if she was in heat. Otherwise, there is no peeing in other parts of the house, except for some small accidents around the litter box.

By the way, she is more affectionate with my husband, prefers to sleep on his side of bed when allowed and loves his sweaty clothes. Both of us tend to her needs (playing, food, cleaning of the litter box), but my husband is doing these more lately.

We don't know how she was raised, how she was treated before she came to us or what kind of environment she was in. We are also not sure if something is wrong with her spaying. Because she becomes more affectionate in certain days of the month as if she was in heat (minus the moaning) and I believe that this peeing thing may correspond to these periods.

Nothing has changed in the house, apart from the fact that we spend more time in the house with her lately, especially my husband. Her litter box is always clean (twice a day) and so far she's never had problem with the litter we prefer.

I tried to be specific as much as I could. Any suggestion about this peeing problem would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does your question differ from this one: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-stop-my-cat-from-peeing-on-rugs-and-linens

Answer (score 1):

I have a VERY similar situation. The only variances are: she ( francie) was about 5 months old (vet was actually off by 2 months on age), she's still very skittish  (we have 2 toddlers to add to the equation,as well) - she's been in the house for almost 6 months now, and I am lucky if she will let me pet her..our other male cat  (sherman)is very affectionate, and she will let me pet her, briefly, while I'm engaging with him. She has never urinated when we were in bed...thank god. Lol. It seems as though, she may choose my side of the bed to mark on as well..

We found that a cheap shower curtain works...tacky, yes, but it works. We lay it out every morning. If I forget, I usualy have surprise waiting !! I can't help but wonder if she dislikes me bc I am the one who took her to the vet to get fixed, vaccinated, etc.

I've also noticed that Francie has several small balls of pee, in the litter box. Where my Sherman has one large ball. (I use clumping litter) no idea if this is in relation, but it is definitely different from any other cat I've owned. Heck, she's different from any other cat I've owned. Lol. I often wonder if the vet would have spayed her right away (going back to the fact that our vet improperly aged her and wouldn't fix her) , before she went into heat, if the problem would have gone away all together!?!
I've read about cats being spayed, while in heat, and the difficulty it causes in removing all tissue, etc....
Uggh. I keep saying I'll give her 6 months, but I dontbthink I can part with her... my heart is too big... I am a sucker. I am thankful it's only once in a while and it's only on my bed.
 Not sure if any of this helps you any, but I'd be happy to hear any updates from you...

Answer (score -1):

Great post, you guys! One of my 2 cats (both neutered males) had taken to painting all of my walls, furniture, and anything else he could reach. I was horrified when I got a UV light. He never did that in all of the 9 years I've had him and didn't when I got him a buddy (they love each other and did so right away) but when a strange black cat started showing up outside both of my cats went nuts and the older one (9) started his wall painting, as well as the curtains out in the kitty room. I couldn't keep up with it.

My cats are indoor cats so it's not like the stray is actually going to get in here but they both hate him (and he is weird...my neighbor's cats hate him too). I've tried cleaning with a pet urine enzyme and then spraying some "No More Spraying" but that hasn't worked.

He's a sneaky little bugger too; he waits until he thinks I'm not looking and then does it. He's learned that the minute I see him backing his butt up to something he gets yelled at. It wasn't until I found "Cat Spraying No More" that I was able to finally get rid of this tiresome behavior. Now my house doesn't smell like a litter box anymore :)

Here's a link the their site if you're interested in checking it out, I highly recommend this: [nomorecatpee.com](http://nomorecatpee.com)

Nabil

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Thanks for your answer - are you affiliated with the website you linked to? You may want to check up on our [promotion page](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) if you are.